# Could not find list of providers cosntant for FirebaseAuth in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am unlinking existing providers in Flutter for FirebaseAuth. I am unable to find the providers constants names like specified in the docs for iOS. However, I cannot find the provider id constants in Flutter. No documentaiton seems to find it. Instead of creating my own constants and keeping them updated, I would like to find the constants from the official packages.

FireBaseAuth Constants: [LINK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Constants)

[image: Firebase Auth Providers Constants]

Currently, I am checking them manually like `facebook.com`, `google.com`, `apple.com` so on.

```dart
 TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

                      print(user);

                      if (user != null) {
                        final providersList = user.providerData;

                        final result = providersList.where((provider) =>
                            provider.providerId == 'facebook.com');

                        if (result.isNotEmpty) {
                          final facebookProvider = result.first;

                          user.unlink(facebookProvider.providerId);
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text('Unlink Facebook'),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constants for those strings are defined [here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/7132d771ed5ada7a0433232b9f0d996ef0d61481/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/auth/Constants.java) in the code for the plugin. But I don't immediately seem an enumeration or something like that of those constants or their string values.

Given what I see elsewhere in the source code of the package, it seems that using the string is the most common (and that constant probably a better alternative).

Comment: I have found the providerId in [Auth Providers](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/7132d771ed5ada7a0433232b9f0d996ef0d61481/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth_platform_interface/lib/src/providers). Here, each provider has a static getter `PROVIDER_ID ` e.g. `FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID` which is what I'm looking for. Would you please update the answer to reflect this?

Comment: If you feel that an edit can improve my answer, go for it (there should be a link right under it for that purpose). You can also post your own, if you think that better answers your question. Just don't forget to update my answer if that was helpful for you to figure it out.

Comment: My suggested edit queue seems to be full. I'll update it later.